# Writing sensor data to text file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write temperature data from two sensors to a text file. I am having problems with this. Can someone please help me with this. The following code is what I have used without success.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Typical reading
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 : crc=41 YES
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 t=23187

while True:

   for sensor in glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0*/w1_slave"):
      id = sensor.split("/")[5]

      try:
         f = open(sensor, "r")
         data = f.read()
         f.close()
         if "YES" in data:
            (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')
            t = float(reading) / 1000.0
         file = open("/var/tmp/temp.txt","w")
         file.write(id,t)
         file.close()
      except:
         pass
 time.sleep(10.0)
```

The original code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import time

# DS18B20.py
# 2016-04-25
# Public Domain

# Typical reading
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 : crc=41 YES
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 t=23187

while True:

   for sensor in glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00*/w1_slave"):
      id = sensor.split("/")[5]

      try:
         f = open(sensor, "r")
         data = f.read()
         f.close()
         if "YES" in data:
            (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')
            t = float(reading) / 1000.0
            print("{} {:.1f}".format(id, t))
         else:
            print("999.9")

      except:
         pass

   time.sleep(3.0)
```

The code prints to screen. I am trying to write to a file.

Comment: you overwrite the same file in each loop, is it intended?

Comment: If there is no "YES" in the data, `t` will be undefined when you do the write.  Did you intend to write the file only if "YES" is found?  And did you intend to append to the file, rather than overwrite it?

Comment: I intend to overwrite the data every 30 seconds. However the data doesn't seem to write to file at all.

Comment: Have you noticed that your indentation does not match the original indentation?  The 3 "file" lines and the "time.sleep" have the wrong indentation.   My answer below is correct.  Do you actually have permission to write to `/var/tmp`?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want.  Where did you learn to use 3 spaces for indenting?  ;)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Typical reading
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 : crc=41 YES
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 t=23187

while True:
   for sensor in glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0*/w1_slave"):
      id = sensor.split("/")[5]

      try:
         data = open(sensor, "r").read()
         if "YES" in data:
            (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')
            t = float(reading) / 1000.0
            with open("/var/tmp/temp.txt","a") as file:
               file.write(id + " " + t + "\n")
   time.sleep(10.0)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I couldn't get this to work. See the original code I've added in the query above. I'm trying to write the data to a file. It shouldn't be difficult but I'm having all sorts of problems. Cheers.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to `/var/tmp`?  If you write to `/tmp` instead, does it work?